# Select popup or modal for huge select lists

Tags: javascript, python, django, select

http://www.advocotek.com/demo/enhancedv2/index.php?module=Accounts&action=EditView&return_module=Accounts&return_action=index

When you open the link, You see arrow icons , upon clicking one, a popup opens and lets you filter and select a record and drops the value for form's text field.

How can I accomplish this? 
I am a python, django user and with a litle javascript knowledge. I need a plug and play way to use this across all form widgets, programatically.
thx.

Comment: This question is far to broad. You are going to have to try to figure it out and then come back when have some code that we can test.

Comment: I could find no sample code to try, having little js knowledge , I cant write it myself. Everytime I ask someone this question they recommed me to use choosen select list.
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/
So I found the solution, giving a link about what I need.

Comment: Well the you are going to have to learn some JS/JQuery before you try and do this. This forum is for specific programming problems not general questions on how to learn to program.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be a request for someone else to write the code, or provide a primer on how to write code, rather than a specific question about programming. You need to show an attempt to write the code yourself and identify a specific question of problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Django admin can do this already, wherever you have a `ForeignKey` field in the `ModelForm` the admin site will show the + button and popup selector functionality you want.

Here is an article about how to achieve the same thing in your own views outside the admin:
http://sontek.net/blog/detail/implementing-djangos-admin-interface-pop-ups

...author has released the code as a reusable Django app:
https://github.com/sontek/django-tekextensions

Here is another app which does more but also includes the functionality you're looking for:
https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/addanother.html

Comment: Thx anentropic, this is a good starting point.
Functionality I want wasnt to create a foreign key record, instead a select one. I will try and modify one of the given resources.